# List of numbers have same data but different sum

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have two lists of numbers. After comparing them with zip(), they are same (at least what I know) but there sum is different.

[image: lists comparison and answers]

You can get the script with list of numbers here as the script is huge, I cannot fix it in this question: https://mega.nz/file/dHgHEQQA#9k9s86hgGH_vWrcE8J6ixYdu3GYkfwtw0V0IBvuhd4o

As you can see, line 1392 is not printing so, the list should be same.

Am I comparing wrong or what is the problem?

Comment: `zip()` is only producing as many results as the length of the shortest list and your lists are not the same length. The sum of the additional elements in the longer list will equal the difference you are seeing

Comment: Oh Thanks, I see the error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of the list. `e` appears to be having `694` elements and `r` appears to be having `693` elements. so, `zip` aggregates only 693 elements. Hence the `sum` are different.

```
print(len(e), len(r), len([x for x in zip(e, r)]))
# 694 693 693
```